# How to add values of a single key in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, sum

Say I have a dictionary:

```
a_dictionary = {"a": [1, 2], "b": [3, 4]}
```

I want to get a resultant dictionary that has the value:

```
a_dictionary = {"a": [3], "b": [7]}
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
for k,v in a_dictionary.items():
    a_dictionary[k] = [sum(v)]
```

Output:

```
>>> print(a_dictionary)
{'a': [3], 'b': [7]}
```